# Should database users also have access to mysql, information_schema & performance_schema tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have for example a table in my database called "Test", I have created a user with `SELECT,INSERT & UPDATE` only privileges. This user will be inserting data to the database. Should this user be limited to only having access to the "Test" table or should they also have access to the 3 tables mentioned above?(obviously these tables come standard with mariadb). Sorry probably a silly question but just want to be sure

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: Is this a question about principle (_should_)?  Or are you asking whether a user _does_  have access to these 3 databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user is restricted with grants to particular database/tables, they will only see those tables.